# Como adicionar marcadores no mapa do google ao clicar nele? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

gostaria de saber como adicionar marcadores ao mapa ao clicar em um ponto no google maps. Na verdade criar/adicionar o marcador "manualmente" eu já sei, o que eu gostaria mesmo era de acionar a função de adicionar o marcador passando as latitudes e longitudes como parâmetro ao clicar no mapa. Aqui está o que eu fiz até agora:

```
var mapa;

criarMapa();

function criarMapa() {
    var latLng = {lat: -8.063074, lng: -34.871129};
    mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latLng
    });

    var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: mapa

    });
}

function adicionarMarcador(latitude, longitude) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        map: mapa
    });

}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o que você precisa é apenas controlar o clique do usuário. No momento do `click` você já consegue esses dados.

Adiciona esse *listener* na inicialização do mapa:

```
mapa.addListener('click', function (e) {
    CarregarEnderecoPorLatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
}
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho aqui amigo. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou aqui, você pode fazer colocando o evento também pelo ponto marcado

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    map: mapa
});

marker.addListener('click', function() {
     console.log("pegou click no marcador");
});
```